# How to find input and simulate change value in vue-test-utils with jest, the best practices

Tags: javascript, vue.js, jestjs, vue-test-utils

I am using Vue, Vuex, Jest.

I have an input which has the **v-model** and **@input** vue attributes.
Testing a component in my tests, I want to find the input and simulate a user's editing.

I've tried `wrapper.setData({myModel: 'new value'})`
and it does not solves the problem since it doesn't trigger **@input**.

Here is what I am doing right now:

```js
const inputWrapper = wrapper.find(".first.second .some-child input");
inputWrapper.setValue('new value');
```

OR

```js
const inputWrapper = wrapper.find(".special-class-for-testing-purposes1 input");
inputWrapper.setValue('new value');
```

And this works fine. Except that I don't really want to use that combination of classes to find the input neither want to modify DOM for tests adding special `class` or `id`.

> Actually, in my case, I am using custom InputField component, so adding new attributes would cause changes of its implementation.

That would be great if I could find my input like so:

```js
wrapper.find({vModel: 'myModel'})
// or
wrapper.findByVModel('myModel')
```

Because in that case, I would not care about

1. How DOM was built
2. What attributes my input has
3. How DOM may change in future

Answer (score 1):

The best way to simulate the typing is:

```
const input =  wrapper.find('input')
input.element.value = newValue
input.trigger('input')
```

Comment: Please, read the description. I want to find an element by my model.

Answer (score 0):

You can't simulate a user's editing by bypassing the DOM and editing model data. User editing happens in the DOM. You have to find the DOM element in which you want the editing to happen and manipulate it to cause it to emit events.

Comment: As I said, I would like to find an element by model name like so wrapper.findByVModel

Comment: You can't find an element by model name. A data item might be bound to multiple elements or none, and might go through a chain of props.

Comment: A class that we pass into the method "find" also may be on multiple elements, so we have the method findAll for that reason.
But okay, what is the common approach here?

Comment: The common approach, as far as I am aware, is to test the implemented structure, and if the structure changes, change the tests.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `@change="xxx"` in your input component, then you can use:

```
const input =  wrapper.find('input')
input.element.value = newValue
input.trigger('change')
```

Edit:

As asked by @Sagid, as far as I know, we have limited set of find methods. So findByVModel is not available apparently.

You can use one of below:

1. wrapper.find(xxx) - if you want to find class '.classname' or by ID find('#myid')
2. wrapper.findComponent(MyComponent)
   I believe this is the closest you can use to find specific custom component. But you must import MyComponent at the beginning.

I hope this would answer your question.

Comment: Please, read the description. I want to find an element by my model.